# Error in DeepSORT with Yolov8 in the line " class_name = get_class(track_id)" : Error AttributeError: 'Track' object has no attribute 'class_id'

Tags: python, deep-learning, video-tracking, yolov8

I need to relate the track_id with the class_name to count the classes but I can't do the relationship as the original code shows, could someone help me?

Below is the code snippet with the error.

```
**for track in tracker.tracks:  
   `` if not track.is_confirmed() or track.time_since_update > 1:  
           continue      
    
    ``bbox = track.to_tlbr()
    
    ``track_id = track.track_id
    
    ``class_name = get_class(track_id)**
```